# How to get predicted labels from model_selection.cross_val_score

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have this code:

```
models=[]

#models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
#models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
#models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
#models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM-linear', SVC(kernel='linear')))
models.append(('SVM-rbf', SVC(kernel='rbf')))
#models.append(('SGD', linear_model.SGDClassifier()))

# evaluate each model in turn
seed=numRow-1
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
for name, model in models:
     kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=seed)
     cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, features, labels, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
     results.append(cv_results)
     names.append(name)
     msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
     print(msg)
```

My problem is: I have 4 data sets, trainingFeatures, trainingLabels, testFeatures and testLabels. How can I teach my model with training sets and test it with testFeatures and then create a predictedLabels to compare it with testLabels. In my code "features" is trainingFeatures+testFeatures and "labels" is trainingLabels+testLabels.

Comment: Dont use `cross_val_score` then. Just call `model.fit(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels)` for training and calculate accuracy for test data using `model.score(testFeatures, testLabels)` inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but does it effect accuracy? Will it be better with crow_val_score, maybe?

Comment: Of course it will. But it makes no sense to compare them.  `cross_val_score` will split the data into different folds as given in KFold and calculate the accuracy of each fold and return the array of all accuracies. In you question you asked how to train on one dataset and test on other set. Thats what I replied.

Answer (score -1):

The way that you use your code and cross val score is correct.

Since, your features variable contain both the training and testing data then the cross val score will split the data to training and testing according to the KFolds that you defined.

Then it will use the test labels to produce the accuracy of each fold.

So by using

```
cv_results.mean()
```

you get the mean accuracy of all the folds.

The other way to do it is to manually define the training and testing features and labels and use fit and predict.